# Marking tests by team name and feature

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

We have a repo containing tests that multiple teams contribute to. As a result, we would like test cases to be marked by `team` and `feature`. We are planning to make these markers mandatory for every test case.

We are experimenting with some options, but are not sure what the 'proper' way to do this is. We came up with these options:

**OPTION 1**:
Create files called `features.py` and `teams.py` and reference them in `feature` and `team` markers:

```
from conf import features, teams

@pytest.mark.feature(features.MY_FEATURE)
@pytest.mark.team(teams.MY_TEAM)
def test_something():
  pass
```

**OPTION 2**: 
Register markers for each individual feature and team, but this feels like it could become messy quick, e.g. in `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --strict-markers
markers =
    feature_MY_FEATURE_1: Labels for test cases by feature or product area
    feature_MY_FEATURE_2: Labels for test cases by feature or product area
    team_MY_TEAM_1: Labels for test cases by team name
    team_MY_TEAM_2: Labels for test cases by team name
```

Is there a better way to do this? Does anyone have any suggestions on how this could be done better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, it's been option 2 and that's what is recommended through their [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#registering-markers). Having all of the marks in a single place like the pytest.ini should make your marks findable.

I've also tried experimenting with the names of the files and using the `-k` keyword search. I found this to be messier, but definitely an option.

Comment: Thanks, that's what we felt made sense too. Too many advantages of just using markers, otherwise running tests by feature/team becomes a pain.